# Combine multiple multi-dimensional data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have multiple image datasets loaded from an HDF5 file. Each dataset is a 4-dimensional data. It consists of various images of size (224,224,3).

I want to combine the data. I searched online and found that using numpy's `vstack()` function is not an efficient way to do this task. Instead, I saw that I should use a python list and then convert it to a numpy array.

Following is the simplified version of the above problem statement which combines 2-3 dimensional data using numpy array:

```py
l2 = np.empty(shape=(1,3,2))

print ("l2.shape : ",l2.shape)

l = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]])

print ("l.shape : ",l.shape)

l2 = np.vstack((l2,l))

print ("l2.shape : ",l2.shape)


l3 = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[4,6]],[[1,2],[3,4],[4,6]]])

print ("l3.shape : ",l3.shape)

l2 = np.vstack((l2,l3))

print ("l2.shape : ",l2.shape)

l2 = np.delete(l2,[0],axis=0)

print ("l2.shape : ",l2.shape)

l2
```

I would like to know if there is a better way of combining multidimensional data (precisely 4-dimensional data of images).

Comment: Why start with that 'empty' (1,3,2) which you later throw away?  `l` is (1,3,2), `l3` is (2,3,2). `vstack` can combine those into a (3,3,2).

Comment: `vstack` (or any 'concatenate.stack') isn't efficient if used itertatively.  But they work just fine on a list of arrays of matching sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concatenate` instead of `vstack`. `concatenate` is more efficient because it pre-assigns memory for the array, thus you don't need to repeatedly resize the array with `vstack`.

```py
import numpy as np

# Example arrays
l = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]])
l3 = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[4,6]],[[1,2],[3,4],[4,6]]])

# Concatenate arrays along the first axis
combined_array = np.concatenate((l, l3), axis=0)

print("Combined array shape:", combined_array.shape)
print(combined_array)
```

This code concatenates the arrays along the first axis, you can modify the axis parameter.

Output:

```
Combined array shape: (3, 3, 2)
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]
  [4 5]]

 [[1 2]
  [3 4]
  [4 6]]

 [[1 2]
  [3 4]
  [4 6]]]
```

Comment: `vstack` uses `concatenate`; read its code.  But yes, in this case combining a (1,3,2) and (2,3,2) with one step is best.